# Splitting set of JSON files using Azure Data Factory into multiple files

Tags: json, azure-data-factory, azure-synapse

I am pulling data from an API at regular intervals (ic every 5 mins or more frequently).
Example of the returned info:

```
{
  "timestamp":"2022-09-28T00:33:53Z",
  "data":[
    {
      "id":"bdcb2ad8-9e19-4468-a4f3-b440de3a7b40",
      "value":3,
      "created": "2020-09-28T00:00:00Z"
    },
    {
      "id":"7f8d07eb-433b-404c-a9b3-f1832bdd780f",
      "value":4,
      "created": "2020-09-28T00:00:00Z"
    },
    {
      "id":"7f8d07eb-433b-404c-a9b3-f1832bdd780f",
      "value":6,
      "created": "2020-09-28T00:05:00Z"
    }
  ]
}
```

So after a certain amount of time I would have a set of files in the landing zone:

- 2022-09-28T00:33:53Z.json
- 2022-09-28T00:43:44Z.json

etc...

I would like to use ADF to take those files and split them on a certain property.
So it would end up in a hierarchy like this:

```
/bdcb2ad8-9e19-4468-a4f3-b440de3a7b40/2022-09-28T00:33:53Z.json
/bdcb2ad8-9e19-4468-a4f3-b440de3a7b40/2022-09-28T00:43:44Z.json
/7f8d07eb-433b-404c-a9b3-f1832bdd780f/2022-09-28T00:33:53Z.json
/7f8d07eb-433b-404c-a9b3-f1832bdd780f/2022-09-28T00:43:44Z.json
```

where each file only has the data related to itself.

Any thoughts on how to pull this off?
Bonus: if for every run of the ADF I could union the files into a single one, that would be great but not absolutely necessary

Answer (score 1):

Read the **source** file.

[image]

From the source file **Data** field will iterate with **ForEach activity.**

[image]

Parameters were provided for the sink dataset with **FolderName** and **FileName**.

[image]

Provided sink folder path and  file path dynamically.

[image]

Values for the given parameters were provided in **COPY ACTIVITY**

[image]

[image]

***Result with Expected files***

[image]